# Erro ao gerar relatorio com Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports

Estou tentando gerar um relatório com `Jasper Reports + JSF` e estou tendo a seguinte exceção:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Invalid page index range : 0
>   - -1 of 0     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:136)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:229)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:116)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printReport(JasperPrintManager.java:313)
>     at bean.InsumosBean.imprimir(InsumosBean.java:95)

Esse é meu código do relatório:

```
public void imprimir(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Imprimir chamado");
            String caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Insumos.jasper");

            Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();

            Connection conexao = HibernateUtil.getConexao();

            JasperPrint relatorio =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, conexao);
            System.out.println(relatorio);
            JasperPrintManager.printReport(relatorio, true); //Linha do erro
        }catch(JRException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar gerar o relatório");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }

    }//Fim do metodo imprimir
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Opa, Crislayne, você verificou a fonte de dados que alimenta o seu relatório? Você alimenta ele via Query ou seria por Collection? Se for o caso de collection você não esta passando no trecho de código acima. Verifica estes detalhes para a gente!

Comment: Ola, Julio Cesar! Então é por query que alimento com conexão por Hibernate. Quando gero ele no Jasper Reports, ele gera normal com os dados do banco na preview.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde! Consegui corrigir.

No Jasper eu tinha criado 2 parâmetros e no meu método eu criei a variável parâmetros, mas não estava passando valores para ela. Para teste eu criei dois puts com os parâmetros passando %% e então ele executou sem erro. Ficou assim:

```
public void imprimir(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Imprimir chamado");
            String caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Insumos.jasper");

            Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();

            parametros.put("TIPO_INSUMO", "%%");
            parametros.put("NOME_INSUMO", "%%");

            Connection conexao = HibernateUtil.getConexao();

            JasperPrint relatorio =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, conexao);
            System.out.println(relatorio);
            JasperPrintManager.printReport(relatorio, true);
        }catch(JRException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar gerar o relatório");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }

    }//Fim do metodo imprimir
```

Obrigado!